# Skype video call recorder for Skype Portable

Tags: windows-7, skype, portable-apps

After a recent reinstall I've decided to almost completely switch over to portable applications whenever I can. This includes installing SkypePortable from portableapps.com.

However, I like to record my skype video calls, but so far I haven't been able to find any **portable** skype call recorders. Previously I've used [Messenger Plus! for Skype](http://www.msgplus.net/Features/For_Skype) but it's not available as a portable application.

Are there any portable skype call recorders out there?

Comment: What do you want to record? Voice? Use Audacity. Video and voice? Any free screen capture software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [iFree Skype Recorder](http://www.ifree-recorder.com/) which records conversations in mp3 format. Works for portable Skype.

Comment: This tool is perfectly free, virus-clean, and works great for me!